# Is there a ceiling ventilation outlet that can be remote controlled to open and close?

Tags: ventilation

I'm trying to work out how I can close off select rooms for a loft-based MHRV unit. I am thinking there's motor based version of [image: pic of circular vent doohickey] but my product searching online is showing nothing.

Like my roller blinds with a remote, I would think it is rechargeable via a USB cable and that I would need to a couple of times a year.

I'm in a retrofit situation - 1971 house with a loft you can't stand up in.

Comment: Why does everyone seem to think that everything in the world should be rechargeable via USB?

Comment: MVHR?  how is it different than an HRV?  You already have an MVHR or are you in planning stages?

Answer (score 4):

There are '[motorised dampers](https://www.ac-one.co.uk/motorised-zone-damper-16220-p.asp)' to put in your ductwork:
[image]

Since these are usually part of a system installation, they're more likely to be hardwired into the control system for your HVAC plant, rather than a standalone item.

Answer (score 2):

I dug a bit more and found an '[electric exhaust air valve](https://www.creoven.co.uk/ventilation-accessories/ave100/a-1180)' ([German source](https://www.ventilator.de/lufttechnisches-zubehoer/tellerventile/ave-100-elektrisch/996583-ave-100), [datasheet PDF](https://www.ventilator.de/datenblaetter/AbluftventilAVE100.pdf)):

(not to be confused with such a device for cars, which are also a thing)

[image]

- System voltage 220V/50Hz
- Current consumption max. 200mA
- Max. electrical opening stroke + 6mm
- Basic ventilation setting range 118mm
- Opening delay 20-35 sec
- Material PP
- Closing delay (subsequent operating time) 10-12 min

It sounds like it has a manual adjustable airflow and then an electrically operated open/close mechanism.  You electrically heat up the thermoelectric thing (maybe wax?) and it opens, then you have to wait for the wax to cool down once power is removed before it closes.